# Easy way to get DB Measurements?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, metrics

My senior management would like to have some counts of database objects (databases, tables, rows, stored procedures, etc) to show complexity to the executive committee. Does anyone know of a quick way to get this information? I'm going after system tables to get the info and some use of sp_MSforeachdb, but I'm hoping maybe someone has a query stored somewhere they can share. Of course it's needed by tomorrow and it's already 3:43 pm. We're using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. And if anyone has ever been in this boat before, is there anything else your management wanted to see?
TIA

Comment: Please see [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckwoody/2007/09/24/script-of-the-day-count-all-objects-in-a-database/) by Buck Woody.  If you search in google `sql server count object by type` you can find bunch of scripts.

Comment: For one thing, [don't use sp_MSforeachdb](https://sqlblog.org/2020/08/04/reliable-flexible-replacement-sp_msforeachdb). It's undocumented, unsupported, and super buggy.

Answer (score 1):

Try [sp_BlitzIndex](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzindex/) with the @Mode = 2 switch for detailed inventories per database including object counts, row counts, and sizes. You can also use the @GetAllDatabases = 1 parameter for system-wide results. (Disclaimer: I’m one of the open source script’s authors.)